# option selected jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Como puedo poner un `option` como selected por medio de una varible donde tengo ya el `ServicioNivelId`.

```
<select class="form-control" id="ServicioNivelId" name="ServicioNivelId">
 <option value="2"> 2do.Nivel</option>
 <option value="3">1er. Nivel</option>
 <option value="5">Nivel de Prueba 2</option>
 <option value="6">3er. Nivel</option>
 <option value="7">4to. Nivel - Fabricante</option>
 <option value="1006">Indefinido</option>
</select>
```

La variable `Servicio` la obtengo por medio de data

```
var Servicio = $(e.relatedTarget).data('servicio');
```

donde data, lo agarro por medio de un botón donde obtengo todos los datos que quiero.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AgentesEdit" 
data-agenteid="@item.AgenteId" data-nombre="@item.Nombre" data-correo="@item.Correo" data-servicio="@item.ServicioNivel.Descripcion" data-telefonooficina="@item.TelefonoOficina" data-telefonomovil="@item.TelefonoMovil" data-rol="@item.Rol"
><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
```

he estado utilizando esto con jquery pero no me funciona.

```
$("#ServicioNivelId option[value='" + Servicio + "'").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haz realizado un console.log(Servicio) de tu variable y ver que el dato que necesitas es el correcto? lo otro creo que falta cerrar con ] el option en tu codigo

```
$("#ServicioNivelId option[value='" + Servicio + "']").attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: sí, cada vez que quiero editar un user de la tabla que tengo, obtengo el dato que quiero en esa variable pero no me funciona lo que le pongo en el jquery

Comment: le agregaste el cierre del corchete y aun asi no funciona? lo otro que puedes probar es $("#ServicioNivelId option[value='" + Servicio + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: No, ni copiando y pegando lo que me pusiste pudo resolver pero intentare lo que me dices

Comment: que extraño, me puedes compartir toda la función jquery, yo probé con datos locales y si me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Me tuve que crear una variable para obtener el select y con el value apuntarlo a la variable que me da el servicioNivelId.

```
var service = document.getElementById("ServicioNivelId").value = Servicio
```

Y en el option ponerlo como selected y darle el valor de la variable `service`